# Can't find error in my SQL using named parameters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

In PHP I'm building, at least trying to, a query using named parameters like so...

```
$answerNumber = "a1";
$questionNumber = "q2";
$answerText = "Test Answer";

//INSERT QUERY
$sql = "INSERT INTO $questionNumber (:answerNumber) VALUES (:answerText)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':answerNumber', $answerNumber);
$stmt->bindValue(':answerText', $answerText);
$stmt->execute();

$errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();

if(isset($errorInfo[2])){
    $error =    $errorInfo[2];
    echo $error;
} else {
    echo "No errors.";
};
```

But I keep getting an error thrown. The error returned...

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''a1') VALUES ('Test Answer')' at line 1

Comment: This `$questionNumber (:answerNumber)` should most likely be `$questionNumber ($answerNumber)`

Comment: placeholders can be used ONLY for values values. You canNOT use placeholders for field/table names, or any other SQL keyword

Comment: Please see the linked question. It mentions table name rather that column but the reasoning is alike.

Comment: Regarding duplication, the answers on this question are much easier to understand than the explanations on the original question. IMHO of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `:`

```
INSERT INTO $questionNumber (:answerNumber) VALUES (:answerText) 
             here------------^
```

use the column name and not the parameter content. You column name is `answerNumber`, right? Because first you have to name the columns you want to insert into. Then list the values in that order. Example:

```
insert into users (id, name) values (1, 'John')
```

and in PDO

```
insert into users (id, name) values (:id, :name)
```